# С++ Обмен данными в локальной сети

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, lan

**Ситуация:** Реализую программу для управления компьютерами локальной сети на С++.

---

**Вопрос:** Как отправить структуру данных от клиента и принять на серверной программе. Дайте пример пожалуйста. Возможно есть спец библиотеки для этого на подобие `curl` для интернета.

---

**Решение:** Оказалось глобальная и локальная сети не такие уж разные как я думал.
Для решения использовать буду Собственный С++ HTTP сервер, а к нему можно из `curl` и браузера обращаться.

Вот код сервера который нашёл на етом же сайте и модифицировал. Программа получает запрос и отправляет в ответ текст из файла index.html если его нет отправляет сообщение что файла нет. Спасибо всем кто участвовал в решении етого вопроса.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

// Для корректной работы freeaddrinfo в MinGW
// Подробнее: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20306451
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

// Необходимо, чтобы линковка происходила с DLL-библиотекой
// Для работы с сокетам
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using std::cerr;

//Получить один из ІР первый попавшыйся
std::string GetIP()
{
std::string out = "WinSock ERR";
WSADATA wsaData;
if (!WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsaData)){char chInfo[64];
if (!gethostname(chInfo, sizeof(chInfo)))
{
hostent *sh;
sh=gethostbyname((char*)&chInfo);
if (sh!=NULL)
{
int nAdapter = 0;
while (sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter])
{
struct sockaddr_in adr;
memcpy(&adr.sin_addr, sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter], sh->h_length);
out = inet_ntoa(adr.sin_addr);
nAdapter++;
}
}
}
}
WSACleanup();
return out;
}

//Получить фаил в формате строки
bool getFile(char* url,std::string &r)
{
    r = "";
    std::ifstream in(url);
            if(in)
            {
                while(1)
                {
                    char t;
                    in.get(t);
                    if(in.eof()) break;
                    r+=t;
                }
            in.close();
            }
            else
            return false;
            return true;
}

int main()
{



    //char *a = (char*)x;

    std::string sIP = GetIP();
    std::cout<<sIP<<'\n';

    WSADATA wsaData; // служебная структура для хранение информации
    // о реализации Windows Sockets
    // старт использования библиотеки сокетов процессом
    // (подгружается Ws2_32.dll)
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    // Если произошла ошибка подгрузки библиотеки
    if (result != 0) {
        cerr << "WSAStartup failed: " << result << "\n";
        return result;
    }

    struct addrinfo* addr = NULL; // структура, хранящая информацию
    // об IP-адресе  слущающего сокета

    // Шаблон для инициализации структуры адреса
    struct addrinfo hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // AF_INET определяет, что будет
    // использоваться сеть для работы с сокетом
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Задаем потоковый тип сокета
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; // Используем протокол TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // Сокет будет биндиться на адрес,
    // чтобы принимать входящие соединения

    // Инициализируем структуру, хранящую адрес сокета - addr
    // Наш HTTP-сервер будет висеть на 8000-м порту локалхоста
    result = getaddrinfo(sIP.c_str(), "80", &hints, &addr);

    // Если инициализация структуры адреса завершилась с ошибкой,
    // выведем сообщением об этом и завершим выполнение программы
    if (result != 0) {
        cerr << "getaddrinfo failed: " << result << "\n";
        WSACleanup(); // выгрузка библиотеки Ws2_32.dll
        return 1;
    }

    // Создание сокета
    int listen_socket = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype,
        addr->ai_protocol);
    // Если создание сокета завершилось с ошибкой, выводим сообщение,
    // освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr,
    // выгружаем dll-библиотеку и закрываем программу
    if (listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Error at socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        freeaddrinfo(addr);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }



    // Привязываем сокет к IP-адресу
    result = bind(listen_socket, addr->ai_addr, (int)addr->ai_addrlen);

    // Если привязать адрес к сокету не удалось, то выводим сообщение
    // об ошибке, освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr.
    // и закрываем открытый сокет.
    // Выгружаем DLL-библиотеку из памяти и закрываем программу.
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        freeaddrinfo(addr);
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Инициализируем слушающий сокет
    if (listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "listen failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    const int max_client_buffer_size = 1024;
    char buf[max_client_buffer_size];
    int client_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for (;;) {
        // Принимаем входящие соединения
        client_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);
        if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            cerr << "accept failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            closesocket(listen_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        result = recv(client_socket, buf, max_client_buffer_size, 0);

        std::stringstream response; // сюда будет записываться ответ клиенту
        std::stringstream response_body; // тело ответа

        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // ошибка получения данных
            cerr << "recv failed: " << result << "\n";
            closesocket(client_socket);
        } else if (result == 0) {
            // соединение закрыто клиентом
            cerr << "connection closed...\n";
        } else if (result > 0) {
            // Мы знаем фактический размер полученных данных, поэтому ставим метку конца строки
            // В буфере запроса.
            buf[result] = '\0';

            // Данные успешно получены
            // формируем тело ответа (HTML)
         /*   response_body << "<title>Test C++ HTTP Server</title>\n"
                << "<h1>Test page</h1>\n"
                << "<p>This is body of the test page...</p>\n";*/

            std::string file;

            std::string zp = buf;
            //int Start = zp.find("GET");
            //int End = zp.find("\n",Start);
            //zp = zp.substr(Start,End);

            //int pos = zp.find("comand=shutdownS",0);

            //if(pos != std::string::npos)
            //std::cout<<pos<<std::endl;

            std::cout<<'\n'<<zp<<'\n';

            if(getFile("index.html",file))
            {       
                    response_body<<file;
            }
            else
            {
                response_body << "<title>Test C++ HTTP Server</title>\n"
                << "<h1>No file index.html</h1>\n"
                << "<p>This is body of the test page...</p>\n";
            }


               /* << "<h2>Request headers</h2>\n"
                << "<pre>" << buf << "</pre>\n"
                << "<em><small>Test C++ Http Server</small></em>\n";*/

            // Формируем весь ответ вместе с заголовками
            response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                << "Version: HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                << "Content-Length: " << response_body.str().length()
                << "\r\n\r\n"
                << response_body.str();

            // Отправляем ответ клиенту с помощью функции send
            result = send(client_socket, response.str().c_str(),
                response.str().length(), 0);

            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // произошла ошибка при отправле данных
                cerr << "send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            }
            // Закрываем соединение к клиентом
            closesocket(client_socket);
        }
    }

    // Убираем за собой
    closesocket(listen_socket);
    freeaddrinfo(addr);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Когда я питаюсь разобраться с кодом всегда убираю лишние проверки
потому вот код без проверок

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    // Для корректной работы freeaddrinfo в MinGW
    // Подробнее: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20306451
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>

    // Необходимо, чтобы линковка происходила с DLL-библиотекой
    // Для работы с сокетам
    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

    using std::cerr;

    //Получить один из ІР первый попавшыйся
    std::string GetIP()
    {
    std::string out = "WinSock ERR";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (!WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsaData)){char chInfo[64];
    if (!gethostname(chInfo, sizeof(chInfo)))
    {
    hostent *sh;
    sh=gethostbyname((char*)&chInfo);
    if (sh!=NULL)
    {
    int nAdapter = 0;
    while (sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter])
    {
    struct sockaddr_in adr;
    memcpy(&adr.sin_addr, sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter], sh->h_length);
    out = inet_ntoa(adr.sin_addr);
    nAdapter++;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return out;
    }


    int main()
    {



        //char *a = (char*)x;

        std::string sIP = GetIP();
        std::cout<<sIP<<'\n';

        WSADATA wsaData; // служебная структура для хранение информации
        // о реализации Windows Sockets
        // старт использования библиотеки сокетов процессом
        // (подгружается Ws2_32.dll)
        int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);


        struct addrinfo* addr = NULL; // структура, хранящая информацию
        // об IP-адресе  слущающего сокета

        // Шаблон для инициализации структуры адреса
        struct addrinfo hints;
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));

        hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // AF_INET определяет, что будет
        // использоваться сеть для работы с сокетом
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Задаем потоковый тип сокета
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; // Используем протокол TCP
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // Сокет будет биндиться на адрес,
        // чтобы принимать входящие соединения

        // Инициализируем структуру, хранящую адрес сокета - addr
        // Наш HTTP-сервер будет висеть на 8000-м порту локалхоста
        result = getaddrinfo(sIP.c_str(), "80", &hints, &addr);

        // Создание сокета
        int listen_socket = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype,
            addr->ai_protocol);
        // Если создание сокета завершилось с ошибкой, выводим сообщение,
        // освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr,
        // выгружаем dll-библиотеку и закрываем программу


        // Привязываем сокет к IP-адресу
        result = bind(listen_socket, addr->ai_addr, (int)addr->ai_addrlen);



        // Инициализируем слушающий сокет
        listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN);



        const int max_client_buffer_size = 1024;
        char buf[max_client_buffer_size];
        int client_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        for (;;) {
            // Принимаем входящие соединения
            client_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);


            result = recv(client_socket, buf, max_client_buffer_size, 0);

            std::stringstream response; // сюда будет записываться ответ клиенту
            std::stringstream response_body; // тело ответа

 if (result > 0) {
                // Мы знаем фактический размер полученных данных, поэтому ставим метку конца строки
                // В буфере запроса.
                buf[result] = '\0';

                std::string file;

                std::string zp = buf;

                std::cout<<'\n'<<zp<<'\n';

                //напечатать ответ
                    response_body << "<title>Test C++ HTTP Server</title>\n"
                    << "<h1>Hello server C++</h1>\n"
                    << "<p>This is body of the test page...</p>\n";




                // Формируем весь ответ вместе с заголовками
                response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                    << "Version: HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                    << "Content-Length: " << response_body.str().length()
                    << "\r\n\r\n"
                    << response_body.str();

                // Отправляем ответ клиенту с помощью функции send
                result = send(client_socket, response.str().c_str(),
                    response.str().length(), 0);

                // Закрываем соединение к клиентом
                closesocket(client_socket);
            }
        }

        // Убираем за собой
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        freeaddrinfo(addr);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
```

Программа при старте в консоль выводить IP адрес который нужно ввести в браузере. Если вы в локальной сети и программа возьмет адрес того адаптера к к которому подключена сеть будь то вайфай или провод любой компьютер локальной сети сможет послать запрос и получить ответ от вашей программы. Есть баг который я незнанию как исправить иногда  страница долго грузиться и не получает ответ но если её перезагрузить ответ мгновенно приходит.

Comment: Tcp/Udp пакет называется, в нем передаётся данные, хоть строка, хоть структура.. суть вопроса отсутствует.

Comment: Не согласен с вами. попробую поискать. если заработает то спасибо.

Comment: По логике, при таком подходе, можно использовать `curl для интернета`, выберите http как транспортный протокол. HTTP серверов и клиентов в каждом языке как минимум несколько готовых реализаций. При всем при этом, писать это вам на C++ крайне не рекомендую, возьмите что то более интуитивное, например `C#`.

Comment: @NewView а какая разница между `c++` и `c#` при работы с сетью? Сеть она и Африке сеть. Писать `HttpClient cl = new Client(...)` или `boost::http_client* cl = new client(..)`, что-то сильно меняет? или влияет на скорость работы?

Comment: @raviga, разница очевидна, автор не понимает чего спрашивает. С C# примеров и готовых решений в разы больше, как раз для копи-пастера. С C++ на много сложнее, от синтаксиса и приведения типов, до отладки, да и кода больше писать на порядок.. что не облегчит понимания. А вообще задача то сиюминутная, на мой взгляд, завтра сдаст домашнее задание и забудет как страшный сон :)

Comment: @NewView ну с такой стороны если посмотреть, то возможно правда

Comment: Я не для универа это делаю. А для себя хочу узнать. Я программирую на С++ OpenGL и хотелось бы уметь реализовать локальную игру. Управления компьютерами это просто  простой пример для меня который поможет разобраться. Возможно я не совсем сети понимаю это да. Мне нужен тип обмена как в контрастрайке импользуеться. И да пока не каких заданий дз Я закончил.

Comment: Тогда внимательно читаем отсюда и пробуем отдельные примерчики из руководства https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: После всего тут написано го реализовал С++ HTTP сервер и странно но по факту могу просто через curl Отправлять данные и получать , Всегда думал что локальная сеть сильно отличается от глобальной.

Comment: Спасибо всем вам

Comment: Странный `class HTTPserver` вы нашли.. реализующий boolean..

Comment: Ето я начал создавать класс чтобы туда весь  этот код упаковать и забыл убрать при публикации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать один из самым популярных вариантов работы с сетью в `C++` это компонент библиотеки `boost` [networking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking.html).

Кроме этого, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library), вы точно сможете найти подходящую библиотеку для решения вашего вопроса, если по каким-то причинам не подойдет `boost`.

Comment: Но мене нужно именно для локальной сети

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка эмм.. а какая разница? Вам все равно нужно подключаться к каким-то "портам" и общаться через сокеты, обмениваясь информацией. `networking` это и есть сеть. А библиотеки выше, это библиотеки для работы с сетью и не важно или вы работаете в скоупе LAN, WLAN, WAN и тп. Возможно вам нужно сначала понять как работает сеть и что это такое?

Comment: Ладно Дайте пожалуйста пример на любой из библиотек как передать структуру через сеть Без доступа к интернету.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка первое, вам нужно `AbstractStructureServer` `API` которого будет знать, как работать с структурой которую вы передаете и сможет ее принимать, а второе вам нужен `AbstractStructureClient`, который будет знать как формировать данную структуру и куда отправлять. На каждом ПК в вашей сети должен быть и клиент и сервер, чтобы они могли обмениваться данными, а для обмена можете использовать библиотеки выше. Я не могу расписать всю теорию до конца здесь, но советую почитать как это работает. 
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/translations/bgnet_A4_rus.pdf